# R: create generic plot in ggplot2

Tags: r

Trying to create a line chart representing a simple slopes analysis. I created the plot using the builtin plot() command. How would I rewrite this code for ggplot2? I tried in ggplot2 but couldn't achieve this figure so I wrote using plot().

Here is the code I used to create my plot.

```
yrange = c(4,7)
xrange = c(-1.5,1.5)
par(bty = 'l')
par(family="Times")
plot(c(-1, 1), c(5.8, 6.2), type='b', lty=1, pch = 15, axes=F, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=yrange, xlim=xrange)
par(new = T)
plot(c(-1, 1), c(5.3, 5.5), type='b', lty=2, pch = 17, axes=F, xlab="IV1", ylab="DV", ylim=yrange, xlim=xrange)
axis(1, at=c(-1,1), labels=c("Cond1", "Cond2"))
axis(2, at=c(4, 5,6,7))
legend("topright", title = "Moderator", c("High", "Low"), lty=1:2)
box()
```

Here is the code I used while trying to create the above figure using ggplot2.  I couldn't fiture out how to create the legend for the moderator, how to change the x-axis labels, add boxes/triangles/circles to the end of the lines, or otherwise the set the lines to look like a proper publication quality APA figure::

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -1, y = 5.8, xend = +1, yend = 6.2), linetype = 1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = -1, y = 5.3, xend = +1, yend = 5.5), linetype = 2) + 
  labs(x = 'IV1', y = 'DV') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(4, 7)) +  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-1, +1, 2)) +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

And, sorry, but this is my first post here. I am interested in using ggplot2 more but it's got a steep learning curve, even for R.

---

@Pdubbs - I updated your code to make it closer to my situation. As I noted below, I'm trying to plot a 2x2 interactions between two continuous variables and the figure I'm creating is to visualize the interaction using a simple slopes regression analysis. Here is what happens and the output when I run this code:

```
> df<-data.frame(DV = c(5.8,5.3,6.2,5.5), 
+                Moderator = c(1,2,3,4), 
+                IV1 = c(6,4,3,2))
> 
> ggplot(df,aes(x=IV1,y=DV,shape=Moderator)) + geom_point() +
+   geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.8, xend = 2, yend = 6.2), linetype = 1) + 
+   geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.3, xend = 2, yend = 5.5), linetype = 2) + 
+   labs(x = 'IV1', y = 'DV') +
+   coord_cartesian(ylim = c(4, 7)) +  
+   theme(legend.position = "bottom")
Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape
```

---

A couple last changes I can't figure out. How to increase the size the endpoints of the lines? For instance, make the triangles larger?

A couple other issues with the legend. First, how to put a black box around the legend? Not a black background, just a simple black box outline around the legend. Second, how to add a solid or dashed line to the legend in addition to the circle or triangle? Third, how to center the legend title text? See the generic plot code as an example of what I mean all 3 of these.

Comment: What `ggplot` commands did you try exactly and where precisely did you get stuck? If you show some effort, this question will be better received. Stack Overflow isn't a code translation service. There should be a specific question here.

Comment: Edit this information into your question so the code can be properly formatted (don't put it in comments). Describe which features exactly you need to re-create.

Comment: you could try ggplot(df,aes(x=IV1,y=DV,shape=as.factor(Moderator)))

Comment: Suggested readings: http://ggplot2.org/book/, http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html

Comment: @MLavoie - shape=as.factor(Moderator) did not help. It treated each moderator value as a different level of the moderator.

Comment: but that's what the error is telling you can't use Moderator for shape; it has to be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be mostly that you're lacking an aesthetic and layer for your data points. `geom_point` will plot datapoints, giving you the legend and shapes on the lines you want. The `aes` inside the main `ggplot` command tells ggplot how the data in df should be plotted. We can get your plot as below:

```
df<-data.frame(DV = c(5.8,5.3,6.2,5.5), 
               Moderator = c("High", "Low", "High", "Low"), 
               IV1 = c("Cond1","Cond1","Cond2","Cond2"))

ggplot(df,aes(x=IV1,y=DV,shape=Moderator)) + geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.8, xend = 2, yend = 6.2), linetype = 1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.3, xend = 2, yend = 5.5), linetype = 2) + 
  labs(x = 'IV1', y = 'DV') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(4, 7)) +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: My original data are two continuous variables. This plot is for a 2x2 interaction between two continuous variables using simple slopes to visualize the interaction. When I use the above command I receive the error message: "Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super late in the game.  I was looking for an entirely different answer, and found this unconcluded question.  First, Pdubbs made the graph.  So, I'm just going to build from that and answer the following: how to make the triangels bigger, how to put a black box around the legend, how to add the lines to the legend, and how to move the legend title.  At the OP request, I've accommodated two continuous variables, and made "Moderator" a factor.  That's just here:

```
df<-data.frame(DV = c(5.8,5.3,6.2,5.5),Moderator = c("1","2","3","4"),IV1 = 
c(6,4,3,2))
ggplot(df,aes(x=IV1,y=DV,shape=Moderator)) + geom_point(size=10) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.8, xend = 2, yend = 6.2), linetype = 1) + 
geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.3, xend = 2, yend = 5.5), linetype = 2) + 
labs(x = 'IV1', y = 'DV') +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(4, 7)) +  
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Note: To change the size of the shapes, you can just use `size=X` in the `geom_point()` call.  So that's the first outstanding answer.

to add the black box you use `+theme(legend.background=element_rect(fill="white",colour="black"))`
To add the lines to the legend you should just be able to add
`,show.legend=T` to the `geom_segment` lines.  Example:

`geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.8, xend = 2, yend = 6.2), linetype = 1,show.legend=T)` You would need that for both lines, I reckon.

To move the title in the legend, you can use this:
`guides(shape=guide_legend(title.position="top"))`

A final run might look like the following:

```
df<-data.frame(DV = c(5.8,5.3,6.2,5.5),Moderator = c("1","2","3","4"),IV1 = 
c(6,4,3,2))
ggplot(df,aes(x=IV1,y=DV,shape=Moderator)) + geom_point(size=4) +
geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.8, xend = 2, yend = 6.2), linetype = 
1,show.legend=T) + 
geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 5.3, xend = 2, yend = 5.5), linetype = 
2,show.legend=T) + 
labs(x = 'IV1', y = 'DV') +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(4, 7)) +  
theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
theme(legend.background=element_rect(fill="white",colour="black"))+
labs(shape="Awesome Sauce")+guides(shape=guide_legend(title.position="top"))
```

The moment may have passed on this, and I think these answers are probably spread throughout the google-sphere somewhere, but hopefully this helps someone.